# Jupyter Notebook doesn’t recognise Anaconda installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

For some reason Jupyter won't recognise the Anaconda installation

```
import os
result = os.popen('conda list anaconda$').read()
print('\nAnaconda Version:\n', result)
```

Result:

Anaconda Version:
packages in environment at C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3:

Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

I've updated the Windows Path variables as follows

C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3;
C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3\Scripts

The conda.exe application is in the Scripts directory

Thanks in advance for any help

**Edit...**

The top 10(ish) rows from running

```
conda list
```

are

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Andy\anaconda3:
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_anaconda_depends         2023.07                 py311_0  
abseil-cpp                20211102.0           hd77b12b_0  
aiobotocore               2.4.2           py311haa95532_0  
aiofiles                  22.1.0          py311haa95532_0  
aiohttp                   3.8.3           py311h2bbff1b_0  
aioitertools              0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
aiosqlite                 0.18.0          py311haa95532_0  
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
anaconda-catalogs         0.2.0           py311haa95532_0  
anaconda-client           1.11.3          py311haa95532_0  
anaconda-navigator        2.4.2           py311haa95532_0  
anaconda-project          0.11.1          py311haa95532_0
```

Comment: Have you tried running in your notebook `%conda list`? Does that list the Anaconda version you want?  If that works, I can tell you how to send the output ultimately to a text string and then parse out the result correctly. As to the problem, I suspect you aren't understanding environments involved here. Minor thing: Because you don't use a code block for your 'Result, it was hard to tell where your result ends and the rest of your post picked back up as I was trying to sort what was going on.

Comment: Yes it does thanks. Result: _anaconda_depends         2023.07                 py311_0

Comment: Also apologies the result ends with the headers Name, Version, Build, Channel but nothing after that

Comment: Good. I'll post my suggestion then. It may take some more input from you to get the parsing just right since I don't know how many instances of Anaconda you have in the list you get back. So you may need to update your post with actual output. I'm having hard time following `Result: _anaconda_depends 2023.07 py311_0` because that looks nothing like what I actually see, but I'm not on Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jupyter, run in a cell in your notebook the following:

```bash
%%capture out
%conda list anaconda$
```

(That sends the result of the `%conda list` to `out`, which is of the type `IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO`. You can read about accessing the various attributes of that [here in the `IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO` documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.capture.html#IPython.utils.capture.CapturedIO). I cover here how I handle it and parse out the version information I think you want next.)

**Then in the next cell**, you can parse collected the information:

```py
out.stdout.split("Channel")[1].split("anaconda",1)[1].split()[0]
```

Based on what you posted in a comment above, you should see:

```
2023.07
```

I actually see `2022.05` when I run it.

---

Your original posted attempt `os.popen('conda list anaconda$').read()` is sending your command to a temporary system shell via `os`, and so that may not be in the exact environment where you notebook kernel is running. `%conda list` uses the magic command to insure things run in the same environment where your kernel backing Jupyter runs.

Comment: Thanks again for this. I was under the impression that not being able to see the anaconda installation would cause me problems later on - perhaps not as it looks like its there. I was following a tutorial. I'm a novice with Python so as you say didn't really understand the environment.